# LayoutCycleDetection - Observablecollection insert twice

Tags: windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I have a strange exception. I get a "LayoutCycleException" when inserting an item into a ObservableCollection two times with a specific index.

Details: I created a Paging-Class, which handles a big ObservableCollection (up to 2000 items) into a single page (200 items). The user can then go to another page. This event causes the Pager to set the page items new. All works fine except one situation: Inserting new items into the page with specific index (0, 1, 2, ..) fires the exception after the second insert.

Anyone an idee why?

Code:

```
// Calculate the index for this page
var cp = (CurrentPage == 0) ? 1 : CurrentPage;
int pindex = index - ((cp - 1) * PageItemCount);
if (pindex >= 0 && pindex < PageItemCount)
{
    // An item is inserted after the list is already loaded
    if (pindex == 0)
    {
        // Check if the page has mor items than it should
        if (_pagedItems.Count >= PageItemCount)
        {
            // Remove last item from page
            _pagedItems.RemoveAt(_pagedItems.Count - 1);
        }

        _pagedItems.Insert(pindex, item);
    }
    else if (_pagedItems.Count < PageItemCount)
    {
        // --> EXCEPTION at third insert
         _pagedItems.Insert(pindex, item);
    }
}
```

**EDIT (solution)**

I found the bug in my code. The Problem was, that the UI had no time to update the collection-changed (UI was not responsive). Very strange bug, took me long time to find it...

A simple *Thread.Sleep(10)* changed the whole thing =) in this time the ui can change the collection and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is not coming from ObservableCollection, but from an event generated when the layout is updated after InsertItem.

LayoutCycleDetection is typically generated when using the LayoutUpdated event handler. You can unintentionally create an infinite loop. In this case _pagedItems.Insert creates a LayoutUpdate event which may be calling _pagedItems to insert again.

If it's not found there, you may have a custom control calling LayoutUpdated and causing the exception.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. I found the Bug in my code. I updated my question.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(10) is masking a more significant problem. You should post the XAML portion that uses _pagedItems so others can find a proper solution.